# Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I am getting this error message when trying to submit a form in django using ajax and I cannot really tell what is bringing up this error. I have tried many solutions but they don't seem to be working as expected. This is the exact error showing up in my console:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=tHTBQbePA8SQrkk9SL18uCsPCIYLE5rey9dFd8vKUhlQDYbh2vLNC5Y5gl3QNXue&full_name=&bio=&email=&phone=:39 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at ?csrfmiddlewaretoken=tHTBQbePA8SQrkk9SL18uCsPCIYLE5rey9dFd8vKUhlQDYbh2vLNC5Y5gl3QNXue&full_name=&bio=&email=&phone=:39:7
```

index.html

```
    <title>Django Form Submission</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center mt-5">Create Profile</h1>
     <h5 class="text-success text-center"></h5>
      <form class="container mt-5" id="post-form">
        {% csrf_token %}

      <div class="mb-3 mr-5 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="full_name" name="full_name"  placeholder="Full Name">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 mr-5 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="bio" name="bio" placeholder="Bio">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 mr-5 ">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
      </div>
      <div class="mb-3 mr-5 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
      
      
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('submit', '#post-form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/create',
          data: {
            full_name: $('#full_name').val(),
            bio: $('#bio').val(),
            email: $('#email').val(),
            phone: $('#phone').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
          },
          success: function (data) {
            ("h5").html(data)
          }
        })
      })
    </script>


  </body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from core.models import Profile
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def create(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        full_name = request.POST['full_name']
        bio = request.POST['bio']
        email = request.POST['email']
        phone = request.POST['phone']

        new_profile = Profile(full_name=full_name, bio=bio, email=email, phone=phone)
        new_profile.save()
        success = 'Profile Created Successfully for ' + full_name
        return HttpResponse(success)
```

Comment: This question was supposed to be closed as a duplicate, your new problem seems to be a new question. (before opening it try to search well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your snippet clearly uses the [JQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery) library, which uses `$` as its namespace. You need to "import" this library, for example through the use of a [CDN](https://releases.jquery.com/) and an appropriate `<script>` tag in your HTML:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: @DestinyFranks: I'll need more information. Is your `create` function called on the server?

Comment: it's working now tnxs